# In Vuforia, my Image Targets are detected. Everything is fine on my laptop, but the GameObject is pink on my Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia, opengl-es-3.0

I'm creating a Vuforia AR Application using Unity3D. I am trying to set up an Image Target that, when detected, plays a video.

This works, the Image Target is detected successfully and the video plays when running it on my laptop. However, when I install it on my Android, I can't see the video. Instead, the video is shown as pink as seen in the image below (at the end). But I can hear the video so it is playing.

I'm using **OpenGLES3** and **OpenGLES2** as Graphics APIs rather than **Vulkan** as I'm integrating the Vuforia application with a Flutter application and those were the recommended Graphics APIs.

The video is being loaded on a Quad that shows up when the Image Target is detected. It's definitely working as it works on my laptop. It just behaves weirdly on my Android phone (Galaxy Note 9, Android 10 if it helps).

Maybe it's the Graphics API? Any suggestion or comment is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!

Turns out Unity was having issues where the emissive texture is not working on the build. All I had to do was add a dummy Material (you don't have to use this anywhere) in the Assets/Resources directory and re-build my App on the phone and it solved my issue.

The videos are now showing.

Comment: On which element did you assign the dummy Material ? I'm also having some troubles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516739/vuforia-on-android-imagetarget-is-detected-one-seconds-and-then-it-doesnt-det