# Vuforia on Android : ImageTarget is detected one seconds and then it doesn't detect anything anymore

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

**Introduction**
I created an app for Hololens 1st gen. The app starts with a menu where the user can chose between different scenario. The 1st and 2nd scenarios use Vuforia in order to detect some `ImageTarget` and replace them with a virtual object. On the Hololens the app is working fine, I can navigate between scenarios and always detect the `ImageTarget`.

**The problem**
I now did the setup in order to deploy this app on Android and the problem I'm facing is that Vuforia detect the `ImageTarget` for like 0.2seconds and then it doesn't detect anything anymore.

**What I've tried**
I had a similar issue on Hololens 1st gen where Vuforia would stop detecting `ImageTarget` when I changed scene, so in order to fix that I added this script on each `ImageTarget`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class debug_change_scene : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
      TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager().ReassociateTrackables();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't help on Android.

**Settings**
In order to deploy my Hololens 1st gen app on an Android device I did the following settings :

- remove Vulcan API
- set minimum level API to 29
- under `Player -> XR Plug-in Management` I selected `ARCore`
- added a Camera Provider to MRTK settings :
  [image]

I use Unity 2019.4.36f1, MRTK 2.8.2.0 and Vuforia 9.8.13

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, I mean I have no idea how this can be a solution but all I had to do was to check the `Allow 'unsafe' code` under `Player -> Other settings`

[image]

Comment: Not fully working like on the helmet but already much better